# android - custom arrayAdapter with asyncTask

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask

I am trying to get html content using custom arrayAdapter and asyncTask implemented in fragment. but the app crashes.
Below is my code.

fragment code

```
package com.example.mohamed.myapplication;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class SecondFragment extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.second_frag, container, false);
    return v;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    new Title2().execute();
}

// Title AsyncTask
private class Title2 extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    String title2;
    String airline;
    Element table;
    Elements myElements;
    weather weather_data[] = new weather[6] ;
    String url2 = "http://www.google.com";

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            // Connect to the web site
            Document document2 = Jsoup.connect(url2).get();
            title2 = document2.title();

            for (int  i= 0; i < 6; i++){
                weather_data[i] = new weather(title2,title2);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        ListView listView2 = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.list2);

        weatherAdapter adapter2 = new weatherAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                R.layout.listview, weather_data);

        listView2.setAdapter(adapter2);

    }
}

public static SecondFragment newInstance(String text) {

    SecondFragment f = new SecondFragment();
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putString("msg", text);

    f.setArguments(b);

    return f;
}
}
```

constructor class

```
package com.example.mohamed.myapplication;



public class weather {
// public int icon;
public String title;
public String description;
public weather(){
    super();
}

public weather(String title, String description) {
    super();
    //this.icon = icon;
    this.title = title;
    this.description = description;
}
}
```

custom arrayAdapter

```
package com.example.mohamed.myapplication;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class weatherAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<weather> {

Context context;
int layoutResourceId;
weather data[] = null;

public weatherAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, weather[] data) {
    super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
    this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
    this.context = context;
    this.data = data;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    weatherHolder holder = null;

    if(row == null)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

        holder = new weatherHolder();
        //holder.imgIcon = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.imgIcon);
        holder.txtTitle = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
        holder.txtDescription= (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.tvDescription);

        row.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
    {
        holder = (weatherHolder)row.getTag();
    }

    weather Weather = data[position];
    holder.txtTitle.setText(Weather.title);
    holder.txtDescription.setText(Weather.description);
    //holder.imgIcon.setImageResource(weather.icon);

    return row;
}

static class weatherHolder
{
    //ImageView imgIcon;
    TextView txtTitle;
    TextView txtDescription;
}
}
```

and here is my logcat

```
12-10 05:03:14.093    1114-1114/com.example.mohamed.myapplication D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed      53K, 4% free 3755K/3872K, paused 2ms, total 3ms
 12-10 05:03:14.097    1114-1114/com.example.mohamed.myapplication D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 3K, 3% free 3973K/4096K, paused 2ms, total 3ms
 12-10 05:03:14.101    1114-1114/com.example.mohamed.myapplication I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 6.356MB for 2536932-byte allocation
 12-10 05:03:14.105    1114-1123/com.example.mohamed.myapplication D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 2% free 6450K/6576K, paused 4ms, total 4ms
12-10 05:03:14.197    1114-1114/com.example.mohamed.myapplication D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_genymotion.so
12-10 05:03:14.197    1114-1114/com.example.mohamed.myapplication D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb8a99d70, tid 1114
12-10 05:03:14.205    1114-1114/com.example.mohamed.myapplication D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_genymotion.so
12-10 05:03:14.205    1114-1114/com.example.mohamed.myapplication D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_genymotion.so
12-10 05:03:14.241    1114-1114/com.example.mohamed.myapplication W/EGL_genymotion﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
12-10 05:03:14.241    1114-1114/com.example.mohamed.myapplication E/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from GradienCache
12-10 05:03:14.245    1114-1114/com.example.mohamed.myapplication E/OpenGLRenderer﹕ MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE: 8192
12-10 05:03:14.249    1114-1114/com.example.mohamed.myapplication E/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from Caches::initConstraints()
12-10 05:03:14.249    1114-1114/com.example.mohamed.myapplication E/OpenGLRenderer﹕ MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE: 8192
12-10 05:03:14.249    1114-1114/com.example.mohamed.myapplication D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
12-10 05:03:34.197    1114-1128/com.example.mohamed.myapplication W/System.err﹕ java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "www.androidbegin.com": No address associated with hostname
12-10 05:03:34.197    1114-1128/com.example.mohamed.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:424)
12-10 05:03:34.201    1114-1128/com.example.mohamed.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
12-10 05:03:34.205    1114-1128/com.example.mohamed.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
12-10 05:03:34.209    1114-1128/com.example.mohamed.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.Dns$1.getAllByName(Dns.java:28)
12-10 05:03:34.209    1114-1128/com.example.mohamed.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:216)
12-10 05:03:34.209    1114-1128/com.example.mohamed.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:122)
12-10 05:03:34.209    1114-1128/com.example.mohamed.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:292)
12-10 05:03:34.213    1114-1128/com.example.mohamed.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:255)
12-10 05:03:34.213    1114-1128/com.example.mohamed.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:206)
12-10 05:03:34.213    1114-1128/com.example.mohamed.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:345)
12-10 05:03:34.213    1114-1128/com.example.mohamed.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:89)
12-10 05:03:34.213    1114-1128/com.example.mohamed.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:449)
12-10 05:03:34.213    1114-1128/com.example.mohamed.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:434)
12-10 05:03:34.213    1114-1128/com.example.mohamed.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:181)
12-10 05:03:34.213    1114-1128/com.example.mohamed.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.get(HttpConnection.java:170)
12-10 05:03:34.213    1114-1128/com.example.mohamed.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at com.example.mohamed.myapplication.FirstFragment$Title.doInBackground(FirstFragment.java:126)
12-10 05:03:34.217    1114-1128/com.example.mohamed.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at com.example.mohamed.myapplication.FirstFragment$Title.doInBackground(FirstFragment.java:105)
12-10 05:03:34.217    1114-1128/com.example.mohamed.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
12-10 05:03:34.217    1114-1128/com.example.mohamed.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
12-10 05:03:34.217    1114-1128/com.example.mohamed.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
12-10 05:03:34.217    1114-1128/com.example.mohamed.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
12-10 05:03:34.217    1114-1128/com.example.mohamed.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
12-10 05:03:34.217    1114-1128/com.example.mohamed.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
12-10 05:03:34.221    1114-1128/com.example.mohamed.myapplication W/System.err﹕ Caused by: libcore.io.GaiException: getaddrinfo failed: EAI_NODATA (No address associated with hostname)
12-10 05:03:34.221    1114-1128/com.example.mohamed.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.Posix.getaddrinfo(Native Method)
12-10 05:03:34.225    1114-1128/com.example.mohamed.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.getaddrinfo(ForwardingOs.java:61)
12-10 05:03:34.225    1114-1128/com.example.mohamed.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:405)
12-10 05:03:34.225    1114-1128/com.example.mohamed.myapplication W/System.err﹕ ... 22 more
12-10 05:03:50.417    1114-1114/com.example.mohamed.myapplication D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 395K, 7% free 7040K/7496K, paused 3ms, total 4ms
12-10 05:03:54.257    1114-1134/com.example.mohamed.myapplication W/System.err﹕ java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "fis.com.mv": No address associated with hostname
12-10 05:03:54.257    1114-1134/com.example.mohamed.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:424)
12-10 05:03:54.257    1114-1134/com.example.mohamed.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
12-10 05:03:54.257    1114-1134/com.example.mohamed.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
12-10 05:03:54.257    1114-1134/com.example.mohamed.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.Dns$1.getAllByName(Dns.java:28)
12-10 05:03:54.257    1114-1134/com.example.mohamed.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:216)
12-10 05:03:54.257    1114-1134/com.example.mohamed.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:122)
12-10 05:03:54.261    1114-1134/com.example.mohamed.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:292)
12-10 05:03:54.261    1114-1134/com.example.mohamed.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:255)
12-10 05:03:54.261    1114-1134/com.example.mohamed.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:206)
12-10 05:03:54.261    1114-1134/com.example.mohamed.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:345)
12-10 05:03:54.261    1114-1134/com.example.mohamed.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:89)
12-10 05:03:54.261    1114-1134/com.example.mohamed.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:449)
12-10 05:03:54.261    1114-1134/com.example.mohamed.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:434)
12-10 05:03:54.261    1114-1134/com.example.mohamed.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:181)
12-10 05:03:54.261    1114-1134/com.example.mohamed.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.get(HttpConnection.java:170)
12-10 05:03:54.261    1114-1134/com.example.mohamed.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at com.example.mohamed.myapplication.SecondFragment$Title2.doInBackground(SecondFragment.java:98)
12-10 05:03:54.261    1114-1134/com.example.mohamed.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at com.example.mohamed.myapplication.SecondFragment$Title2.doInBackground(SecondFragment.java:74)
12-10 05:03:54.265    1114-1134/com.example.mohamed.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
12-10 05:03:54.265    1114-1134/com.example.mohamed.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
12-10 05:03:54.265    1114-1134/com.example.mohamed.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
12-10 05:03:54.265    1114-1134/com.example.mohamed.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
12-10 05:03:54.265    1114-1134/com.example.mohamed.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
12-10 05:03:54.265    1114-1134/com.example.mohamed.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
12-10 05:03:54.265    1114-1134/com.example.mohamed.myapplication W/System.err﹕ Caused by: libcore.io.GaiException: getaddrinfo failed: EAI_NODATA (No address associated with hostname)
12-10 05:03:54.265    1114-1134/com.example.mohamed.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.Posix.getaddrinfo(Native Method)
12-10 05:03:54.265    1114-1134/com.example.mohamed.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.getaddrinfo(ForwardingOs.java:61)
12-10 05:03:54.265    1114-1134/com.example.mohamed.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:405)
12-10 05:03:54.265    1114-1134/com.example.mohamed.myapplication W/System.err﹕ ... 22 more
12-10 05:03:54.281    1114-1114/com.example.mohamed.myapplication D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
12-10 05:03:54.281    1114-1114/com.example.mohamed.myapplication W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa4d1eb20)
12-10 05:03:54.285    1114-1114/com.example.mohamed.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.mohamed.myapplication, PID: 1114
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
        at com.example.mohamed.myapplication.flightAdapter.getView(flightAdapter.java:35)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2255)
        at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1263)
        at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1175)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChild(RelativeLayout.java:689)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:473)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1456)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
        at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:327)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2291)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1912)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1109)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1291)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:996)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5600)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

can you please look at the logcat and tell me what is wrong with the code.

is there anything wrong with this line

```
private class Title2 extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
```

Do i haave to pass any parameter?

Thanks in advance

flightAdapter class

```
package com.example.mohamed.myapplication;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class flightAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<flight> {

Context context;
int layoutResourceId;
flight data[] = null;

public flightAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, flight[] data) {
    super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
    this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
    this.context = context;
    this.data = data;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    flightHolder holder = null;

    if(row == null)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

        holder = new flightHolder();
        //holder.imgIcon = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.imgIcon);
        holder.txtTitle = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
        holder.txtDescription= (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.tvDescription);

        row.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
    {
        holder = (flightHolder)row.getTag();
    }

    flight Flight = data[position];
    holder.txtTitle.setText(Flight.title);
    holder.txtDescription.setText(Flight.description);
    //holder.imgIcon.setImageResource(Flight.icon);

    return row;
}

static class flightHolder
{
    //ImageView imgIcon;
    TextView txtTitle;
    TextView txtDescription;
}
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
    at com.example.mohamed.myapplication.flightAdapter.getView(flightAdapter.java:35)
```

Looks like in your class "flightadapter", your trying to cast an Application to an Activity...line 35

Comment: I think that error happens after app failed in a previous error, probably the UnknownHostException.

Comment: Nope. That's all the stack trace says about your app. Could you post the code for fliightadapter?

Comment: i have added flightAdapter class

Comment: Your issue is in the line LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater(); ...change that to LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);    If you're interested in knowing WHY your error is happening, it's because your casting an Application to an Activity, which it is not. Try not to do this in the future :)